# CSS3 Target last letter of placeholder or *

Tags: css

I've got this problem, where I need to change the color of the "*" in a placeholder.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Name*">
```

I need to make the color of the "*" blue, and I'd prefer using only CSS, but I'm not sure that's possible.

I know there's a ::first-letter, is there a ::last-letter or something? :-)

Answer (score 4):

This is impossible. There is no way to style that part of the attribute value.

That said, it looks like you are trying to use the placeholder attribute is as a substitute for the label element, [which it is not](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/).

If you used a `<label>` element, you could put a span around the character and target that with a descendant combinator.

Comment: Well, the <label>-trick is not possible, as it's in a placeholder. But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: That's what CSS is for.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" class="f_name" name="fname" placeholder="First Name*">
```

and the css part:

```
input {
padding: 10px;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #AAA 0%, #AAA 46%,red 46%, 
red 100%);
-webkit-background-clip: text;
-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

I have tried this and it worked, give it a try @Jeppe Stenstrup